# C# program return the powered on machine connected through Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have an application that list all the machines in my network. All those machines are registered in Active Directory in the same domain.

I want to know which machine is turned on and connected to the network and which one is not.

Is there a way to do that with C#?

Comment: WMI (Windows Management Interface) would be the API that would let you do that, if it's at all possible.  There is a C# interface to it (MIcrosoft.Management.Infrastructure): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-with-c-

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function to check if one server is online. Once you have that method, you can run over your list of servers (from AD or csv) and see which one is online / offline.

Following example shows how you can print results in the Console or use of a dictionary to store the resulst.

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation; // Required for Ping()

public static bool IsServerPingable(string server)
{
    try
    {
        var ping = new Ping().Send(server);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Use in the main

List<string> servers = new List<string>() { "server1", "server2", "server3", "server4", "server5" };
Dictionary<string, bool> serverStatus = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

Parallel.ForEach(servers, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, (server) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{server} online: {IsServerPingable(server)}");
    serverStatus.Add(server, IsServerPingable(server));
});
```

To check if the server is on the domain, you'll need to write another method that would use the WMI (like @Flydog57 mentioned).